# Why tmux window in iterm2 has different appearance?

Tags: tmux, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

While using tmux in iTerm2 (both normally and using -CC native integration), I noticed that tmux window is of a different style compared to the original iTerm2 window. Specifically, the color theme (Material) is preserved as I see (deep blue background of a window), but the command line itself (hence, I suppose this is oh-my-zsh configs) are not preserved. See the picture attached.

I'd like to know why, and how to make them of one style.

iTerm2 original window:

[image]

tmux window inside iTerm2:

[image]

Comment: What is the value of the `TERM` environment variable in and outside `tmux`?

Comment: Inside tmux it is `screen`, outside `xterm-256color`. Interesting..
Not sure why such a complication of a tmux window to have a different view setting. At which point and how can I not set up tmux view a-new but just say "make as the parent window"?

Comment: In your `.tmux.conf`, add something like `set -g default-terminal screen-256color`, so that programs running under `tmux` know that the terminal can still handle 256 colors, even if `tmux` is mediating all communication between the programs and the actual terminal.

Comment: This fixed the colors, thank you!
I have a couple of questions left though. Maybe you can help.

1) I suppose this is the oh-my-zsh feature that was ignored/overwritten. Could it be that some other features will be ignored too, since we fixed just a color part of oh-my-zsh setting? Feels like just a trick with this direct color re-setting

2) Is it important which tmux.conf file to change? I have two: 
`~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/tmux/tmux.extra.conf`, `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/tmux/tmux.only.conf`

Comment: I have no idea how that particular `tmux` plugin works. But with `TERM=screen` inside `tmux`, you were basically telling any program that cares about the difference between color and monochrome terminals that you were using a monochrome terminal.